# Get the final SQLite expression when using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, backtrace

I experience some weird results on certain queries to an SQLite database. Therefore I'd like to see the real query sent to the database. I'm using PDO, and the closest I can get is

```
$statement->debugDumpParams();
```

but this is just an abstract representation, not the final query.

Is there any way to see, what's actually sent to the db driver? There seems to be a C interface [trace()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/profile.html), but as far as I can tell, I have no means of accessing it from within PHP.

Comment: Isn't that actually what is sent to driver? Statement and parameters separately?

Comment: OK, in that case, can I have the DB driver itself give debug info?